# Multi authentication for email verification | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In registeration system of laravel there is a function guard()

```php
protected function guard(){
   return Auth::guard();
}
```

in location

> vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegisterUsers.php

and the function of register uses this guard function

```php
public function register(Request $request){
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 201)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

and when I want to make a registration system for another guard I just will overwrite the function guard function and meke it like that

```php
protected function guard(){
   return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

and all of that are very nice
but in the email verification, the function of guard() dosen't exist
and it use
 `$request->user()`
instead like that

```php
public function resend(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 202)
                : back()->with('resent', true);
}
```

So, what if I want to overwrite the guard in this case
I thought to overwirte the whole function of (resend) but i think it's not the best solution
So can anyone tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting the function of guard
I just will use
`shouldUse()` function in the constructor
like that
`auth()->shouldUse('admin');`
and then when I use `request->user()` it automatic will use it as an admin guard